# Query xml data - sample data from Microsoft not working

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am looking for a solution where I do not need to edit the file, or the copy pasted content manually. I am trying to use this method to query a xml document

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml  
DECLARE @ProdID int  
SET @myDoc = '<Root>  
<ProductDescription ProductID="1" ProductName="Road Bike">  
<Features>  
  <Warranty>1 year parts and labor</Warranty>  
  <Maintenance>3 year parts and labor extended maintenance is available</Maintenance>  
</Features>  
</ProductDescription>  
</Root>'  
  
SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(/Root/ProductDescription/@ProductID)[1]', 'int' )  
SELECT @ProdID
```

Example from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/value-method-xml-data-type?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-the-value-method-against-an-xml-type-variable

But when I try to use this sample data it will not work when I want to set the variable. My xml files also include single quotes that is why I choose this example.

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml  
DECLARE @ProdID int  
SET @myDoc = '<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>'
```

Sample data from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms762271(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample data you have selected contains a quote `'`.

```
...
<title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
...
```

This breaks the literal string definition. The SQL engine thinks that the string ends after `Developer` and does not know what to do with the rest of that string and tries to tell you with 2 errors...

> Msg 102 Level 15 State 1 Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near 's'.

> Msg 105 Level 15 State 1 Line 23
> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '  '.

You can fix this by "escaping" the single quote with another quote like so:

```
...
<title>XML Developer''s Guide</title>
...
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c76d602b824eaa5c8ea88ec0eb073586)

Comment: But I cannot do this to my real files i.e. change them manually.

Comment: I can search and replace. But there must be another solution

Comment: Depends on how you populate your XML variable with your "real files". Please create a new question that shows how you load your real files.

Comment: For now I just copy-paste the content in SSMS. When I have found a solution for this I will figure out how to proceed.

Comment: My files are many thousand lines, you say the solution is to find all the single quotes and escape them? I could of course do a search and replace...

Comment: I was expecting you to no copy-paste them... Have a look a [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/) to import an entire file into one column or [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5707/simple-way-to-import-xml-data-into-sql-server-with-tsql/) to import the XML values in separate columns. [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16838627/import-xml-into-sql-server) of that last scenario.

Comment: I cannot use bulk operation I have tried it says I do not have permissions... At least when I try to import xml... I will try to import the whole thing in one column...Thanks

Comment: I tried the first link it says You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement. Strange.. I can drop the database if I want but I cannot read a file...

Comment: The lack of permissions was (and currently still is) not part of your original question. This changes the question completely. With this new information I suggest you contact your database administrator to grant you the required privileges.

Comment: So with the copy-paste method in SSMS the only solution is to escape the single quotes?

Comment: As far as I can tell that would indeed be the case with your current approach. In order to validate this, please create a **new question** that shows how you attempted the bulk load of the XML document(s). Copy-paste the exact error message(s) you received.